# Noob to electronjs: Question about contextBridge / appropriate usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm quite new to ElectronJS and much of my learning has come from examples and docs since it seems many tutorials out there are outdated especially due to the addition of enforcing nodeIntegration: false and contextIsolation: true.

My research has led me down the path of preload scripts, which by themselves still open themselves up to vulnerabilities, which then led me to contextBridge via preload scripts.

As a disclaimer, what I'm doing is probably unnecessary since I'm not actually connecting to any third-party and everything is local, so theoretically I could edit the webPreferences for nodeIntegration and contextIsolation. However, for my own learning purposes as well as best practice, I felt it necessary to understand how to do what I want to do and expose APIs such as require, fs, path, os etc. without using a "deprecated" feature.

Mainly wanted to post here to see if this is the proper method of using contextBridge.

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const os = require("os");

...

let mainWindow;

function createMainWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    title: "Test",
    icon: `${__dirname}/assets/icons/Icon_256x256.png`,
    width: isDev ? 800 : 500,
    height: 600,
    resizable: isDev,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    webPreferences: {
      preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
    },
  });

...

ipcMain.handle("get-file-path", async (event) => {
  const filePath = path.join(os.homedir(), "test");
  return filePath;
});

...
```

preload.js

```
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
  getFilePath: async () => {
    const res = await ipcRenderer.invoke("get-file-path");
    return res;
  },
});
```

renderer.js

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  document.getElementById("output-path").innerText =
    await window.api.getFilePath();
});
```

It works as intended. From my understanding of what is happening here is by using contextBridge with a callback method I'm essentially keeping everything isolated within that function and not exposing anymore that what's within that closure--is that correct?

Once again, I'm really new (1 day into electron essentially). I've only been 'developing' for 7 months or so.

Would this also be valid.. offloading to another js file and exposing those functions through context bridge?

test.js

```
const path = require("path");
const os = require("os");

const getFilePath = () => {
  const filePath = path.join(os.homedir(), "test");
  return filePath;
};

module.exports = {
  path: getFilePath,
};
```

preload.js

```
const { contextBridge } = require("electron");
const mainFunctions = require("./test.js");
const { path } = mainFunctions;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
  getFilePath: path(),
});
```

Both give me the outcome I expect.